# Prolog Shift n times a list function either way

Tags: prolog

I have to define a predicate nshift/3 that shift a list N times either way. 
Examples:

```
?- nshift(3,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],Shifted). 
  Shifted = [d,e,f,g,h,a,b,c]   
?-­nshift(1,[1,2,3,4,5],Shifted).   
  Shifted = [2,3,4,5,1]
?-­nshift(-2,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h],Shifted).    
  Shifted = [g,h,a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

I created a code that would take care of the first two examples but I'm having problem with the last example where the N time is -2. Can somebody help me. 
My code:

```
my_shift([], []).
my_shift([H|T], L) :-
   append(T, [H], L).

nshift(0, L, L) :- !.
nshift(N, L1, L2) :-
   N1 is N-1,
   my_shift(L1, L),
   nshift(N1, L, L2).
```

Comment: I don't know prolog, but shouldn't you compare the number to 0 at some point?

Comment: @Teepeemm that happens implicitly with the first `nshift/3` rule the OP devised.

Comment: I know this sounds trivial, but to handle the negative shift case, negate the value to be positive and shift the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this old code

```
rotate(right, L, [T|H]) :- append(H, [T], L).
rotate(left, [H|T], L) :- append(T, [H], L).
```

Then, I think you could adapt your nshift/3 testing if the first argument is < 0, something like

```
nshift(0, L, L) :- !.
nshift(N, L1, L2) :-
  N < 0, rotate(right, L1, L), N1 is N+1, nshift(N1, L, L2).
nshift(N, L1, L2) :-
  N > 0, rotate(left, L1, L), N1 is N-1, nshift(N1, L, L2).
```

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in another answer, your type of *shift* is usually called *rotate*.  Rotates with non-negative N can be written in a nicely declarative way as

```
naive_rotate(N, Xs, Ys) :-
    length(Bs, N),
    append(As, Bs, Xs),
    append(Bs, As, Ys).
```

While this works, people will be quick to point out that its termination properties are poor: when you backtrack into `rotate/3`, i.e. ask for more solutions, it will not terminate.  This can be addressed by adding redundant conditions on the list lengths, viz.

```
rotate(N, Xs, Ys) :-
    same_length(Xs, Ys),
    leq_length(Bs, Xs),
    length(Bs, N),
    append(As, Bs, Xs),
    append(Bs, As, Ys).

  same_length([], []).
  same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :- same_length(Xs, Ys).

  leq_length([], _).
  leq_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :- leq_length(Xs, Ys).
```

This now works nicely for various query patterns, e.g.

```
?- rotate(2, [a,b,c,d,e], Ys).   % gives Ys = [d,e,a,b,c]
?- rotate(2, Xs, [a,b,c,d,e]).   % gives Xs = [c,d,e,a,b]
?- rotate(N, [a,b,c,d,e], Ys).   % 5 solutions
?- rotate(N, Xs, [a,b,c,d,e]).   % 5 solutions
?- rotate(N, Xs, Ys).            % many solutions
```

You can then write your original `nshift/3`  as

```
nshift(N, Xs, Ys) :-
    ( N>=0 -> rotate(N, Xs, Ys) ; M is -N, rotate(M, Ys, Xs) ).
```